# How to find YII routes from url

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I am new in Yii Framework. I am doing one small correction in Yii framework web app. Their third party Fax(Fax.de) API providers change something, I am trying to change the code, but I couldn't get the right file.

If the URL is **www.example.com/paymentoption**. What controller will work and where can I get Route folder?

Please help me...

Comment: Besides the below answers, you should check your app config file about some `urlManager` `rule` that could be redirecting your `paymentoption` to any other place else than 'conventional' place.

Answer (score 3):

in yii there is no route folder or file.
From Url you can simply find the controller named paymentoption. and in that you can find the method actionIndex which is called by Default

Answer (score 2):

From documentation:

> Routing involves two steps:
>
> the incoming request is parsed into a route and the associated query
>   parameters; a controller action corresponding to the parsed route is
>   created to handle the request. When using the default URL format,
>   parsing a request into a route is as simple as getting the value of a
>   GET query parameter named r.
>
> When using the pretty URL format, the URL manager will examine the
>   registered URL rules to find matching one that can resolve the request
>   into a route. If such a rule cannot be found, a
>   yii\web\NotFoundHttpException exception will be thrown.
>
> Once the request is parsed into a route, it is time to create the
>   controller action identified by the route. The route is broken down
>   into multiple parts by the slashes in it. For example, site/index will
>   be broken into site and index. Each part is an ID which may refer to a
>   module, a controller or an action.

In this case, the link:  **www.example.com/paymentoption** will use the controller **PaymentoptionController** and **actionIndex**, or it could be a module.

I recommend reading the documentation on the part of the **Routing** and **Url manager**: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing

Answer (score 1):

Yii is a conventional based framework. That is, You should follow certain naming conventions to create your component.

For example. Your controller should be

```
    SomenameController
```

Notice, above controller name has naming convention `Controller` adjoined to `Somename`

Here, You don't have folder to router, but controllers

```
     //Get controller name
     echo Yii::$app->controller->id
```

You can find a controller with that name in your controllers folder.